# need <unrar/dll.hpp> to pip install unrardll on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, rar, pip

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, Calibre gives this error when opening a .cbr file:

> ```
> calibre, version 3.21.0
> ...
>     File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/unrar.py", line 53, in extract
>        from unrardll import extract
> ImportError: No module named unrardll
> ```

Okay, so...

```
#> sudo pip install unrardll
```

...

```
src/unrardll/wrapper.cpp:19:10: fatal error: unrar/dll.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <unrar/dll.hpp>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

Hmm...

```
#> dpkg -S unrar/dll.hpp
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *unrar/dll.hpp*
```

How do I install the unrardll Python module on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: can you accept the answer provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unrar` sources, development files and library aren't packaged for Ubuntu, so you'll need to get them and install them yourself...

There is an "*UnRAR source*" download on the ["*extras*" page of rarlab.com](https://rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) - use this link with `wget` below.

You'll need to build and install the library, and then use the `--global-option` with `pip` to point it at the headers.

Follow along below:

```bsh
apt update
apt install -y build-essential python-pip wget
mkdir unrarsrc
cd unrarsrc
wget https://rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.6.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf unrarsrc-5.6.8.tar.gz
make -C unrar lib
sudo make -C unrar install-lib
sudo pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I$(pwd)" unrardll
```

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unrardll
>>>
```

Please note that after doing this, the UnRAR library will be under your control, and thus *you* will be responsible for updating it. The `unrar` utility will still be provided by the package manager, so will update as normal.

---

There is a PPA that provides the packages required for this, but the most recent version of Ubuntu supported is "*Saucy Salamander*" (13.10), last updated ~5 years ago with unrar v5.0.14.

https://launchpad.net/~trinitronx/+archive/ubuntu/unrar-nonfree

Comment: Great, one change needed for bounty however. The wget needs to be done _after_ the `cd unrarsrc-5.6.8` in order for your `tar -xvf unrarsrc-5.6.8` to be successful. Also a `sudo` in front of `make -C unrar install-lib`

Comment: done - I usually prefer to avoid providing `sudo`, but I've added it anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, however most in the Ubuntu desktop realm that will be using this will be in the context of a non-priviledged user.

Comment: I know - I like people to think about privilege and use of `sudo` for themselves ;-)

Comment: Now that the required time has passed, bounty awarded. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

first do `make lib` `make install-lib`
then, try `pip install unrar`